# Trying to add delegated permission scopes defined in Azure Virtual Desktop RBAC to AAD App registration by calling Microsoft Graph API - /applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, windows-virtual-desktop

Cannot pass delegated permission scopes related to Azure Virtual Deskltop RBAC based permissions like Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostpools/*/read
defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/rbac
as they are not listed in the full list defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#all-permissions-and-ids

Trying to add delegated permission scopes to AAD App registration by calling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
The full list of permission scope that can be passed is defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#all-permissions-and-ids
does not contain Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above documentation you have shared I was able to conclude that each RBAC role comes with a set of permission (which could not be assigned individually with built in roles).

For example [Desktop Virtualization Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/rbac#desktop-virtualization-reader) come with following permissions:

Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization//read,*

Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read,

Microsoft.Resources/deployments/read,

Microsoft.Authorization//read,*

Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/read,

Microsoft.Support/*

The reference GUID in Azure AD Graph API for [Desktop Virtualization Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#desktop-virtualization-reader) is 49a72310-ab8d-41df-bbb0-79b649203868 reference doc [Azure built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles).

> You could assign the roles via REST API and not via Graph because
> Graph API only manages Azure AD resources rather than Azure resources.

- Get the [Role Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-assignments/list-for-resource?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) - List For Resource

Example:

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/4455e754-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-aa0623375982/resourceGroups/B2C/providers/Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostpools/HOSTPOOL1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01

- Compare the role with [Virtual desktop infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#virtual-desktop-infrastructure) for permission and [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#virtual-desktop-infrastructure for Role ID
- [Use Role Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-assignments/create?tabs=HTTP) - Create

PUT [https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{roleAssignmentName}?api-version=2022-04-01](https://management.azure.com/%7Bscope%7D/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/%7BroleAssignmentName%7D?api-version=2022-04-01)

[image]

Please do let me know if you have any further queries in the comments section.

Thanks,